# Show the declared variable value while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[testdate]
as  
begin    
   declare @current nvarchar(100),     
           @date1 datetime    

   select @current = getdate()    
   select @date1 = getdate()  
end
```

While executing I want to show the values of `@current` and `@date1`..

How can I declare these two variables?

Now I am getting 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @curent nvarchar(100),
            @date1 datetime

    SELECT @curent=getdate()
    SELECT @date1=getdate()

    SELECT @curent
    SELECT @date1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [OUTPUT keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get these values from your stored procedure

```
declare
@curent nvarchar(100) OUTPUT,
@date1 datetime OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
alter procedure [dbo].[testdate] as
begin
declare
@curent nvarchar(100),
@date1 datetime
select @curent=getdate()
select @date1=getdate()
select @curent as "CurrentDate"
select @date1 as "Date1"
end
```